# Flexform field select length of items

Tags: typo3, flux, fedext

I have an interesting issue with a flux:flexform.field.select. Currently my set-up looks like.

```
<flux:flexform.field.select
name="link_type"
required="true"
default="5"
items="{
    1: {0: 1, 1: 'LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:flux.icon_link.fields.link_type.type-1'},
    2: {0: 2, 1: 'LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:flux.icon_link.fields.link_type.type-2'},
    3: {0: 3, 1: 'LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:flux.icon_link.fields.link_type.type-3'},
    4: {0: 4, 1: 'LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:flux.icon_link.fields.link_type.type-4'},
    5: {0: 5, 1: 'LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:flux.icon_link.fields.link_type.type-5'}
}" />
```

But this is causing an error and so my complete tab is not showing up in the "New Content Element" section. It appears to be to do with the length of the items section as I can remove any 2 of these items and it will work. I cannot see anything in the error logs.

How are new tabs in the "New content element" section created? Or is there any known issue with items length?

Comment: We have done a little more investigation, here is additional details
https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/344

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the issue us solved for all other members of my team the first option worked, for me the second was hiding the fact that the first worked:

1. The Apache stack size should be increased. The Typo3 install tool advised us to insert the following to httpd.conf.

   `ThreadStackSize 8388608`
2. We experienced a kind of encoding problem, the db dump which was used for dev environment initialization was broken in terms of encoding. Any installation of Typo3 + Fluid is broken with that dump.